# 16 bit assembly prints extra unknown characters

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I want to print simple *hello world* with 16 bit assembly (winasm IDE and masm) but before "hello world" unknown characters shown.
here is code:

```
.MODEL small
.STACK 100h
.data
message db "Hello, world!$"
.code
_start:
    mov ah,9
    lea dx,message ; addr of buffer
    int 21h
    mov ah,1
    int 21h
END _start
```

Comment: Can you show the output?  Do you have `ds` set correctly?

Comment: thanks to Carl Norum I set ds and problem solved!

Comment: but why needed to set ds?

Comment: Because the string pointer for `int 21/9` needs to be in `ds:dx`.  Have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not very sure about MASM syntax, but you must set DS register with something like:

```
    mov  ax, @data  ; if the .data labels points to your data segment
    mov  ds, ax
; then your code
    mov  ah, 9 ..........
```

Comment: yes, it's true but I think in masm should use @data instead of .data . thanks alot johnfound

Answer (score 0):

You have to move CS into DS before executing any code.

```
.code
start:
    push cs ; <-- important!
    pop ds ; <-- important!
    ; -- your codes here --
    mov eax, 9h
    ...
    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h
end start
```